# What is Action<string>?

Tags: c#, generics, delegates

What is `Action<string>`, how can it be used?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

`Action` is a standard delegate that has one to 4 parameters (16 in .NET 4) and doesn't return value. It's used to represent an action.

```
Action<String> print = (x) => Console.WriteLine(x);

List<String> names = new List<String> { "pierre", "paul", "jacques" };
names.ForEach(print);
```

There are other predefined delegates :

- `Predicate`, delegate that has one parameter and returns a boolean.

  ```
  Predicate<int> predicate = ((number) => number > 2);
  var list = new List<int> { 1, 1, 2, 3 };
  var newList = list.FindAll(predicate);
  ```
- `Func` is the more generic one, it has 1 to 4 parameters (16 in .NET 4) and returns something

Comment: I believe "1 to 16 parameters" is only available from .NET 4 though?

Answer (score 12):

This is a delegate to a function with the signature 
`void Bla(string parameter)`. You can use this to pass functions to other functions.
For instance you can do this

```
Action<string> action = (x => Console.WriteLine(x));
new List<string>{"1","2","3"}.ForEach(action);
```

to print all characters to the console

Answer (score 7):

It is a delegate with one parameter, this being a string.

Useful because it means you do not have to create delegates anymore for actions as long as you can use a standard action for them (i.e. the number of parameters is fixed, no default values and you can just use an existing action).

Answer (score 2):

```
public void ValidateInput(string input)
{
   //some code
}

public void test()
{
   Action<string> action = ValidateInput;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is basically just a delegate that does not return a value.

Have a look here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8.aspx

`Action<string>` would just be a delegate of a method that excepted a single string parameter and did not return anything.