# Newbie, howto to start this function

Tags: c#, function, calling-convention

please sorry for this stupid question, i'm newbie to c# and my Vb is untouched by many years..

Based on this article: [Process Start](http://csharptest.net/532/using-processstart-to-capture-console-output/)

Here the code:

```
 public static int Run(Action<string> output, TextReader input, string exe, params string[] args)
  {
     if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(exe))
        throw new FileNotFoundException();
     if (output == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("output");

     ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
     psi.UseShellExecute = false;
     psi.RedirectStandardError = true;
     psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
     psi.RedirectStandardInput = true;
     psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
     psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
     psi.ErrorDialog = false;
     psi.WorkingDirectory = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
     psi.FileName = FindExePath(exe); //see http://csharptest.net/?p=526
     psi.Arguments = EscapeArguments(args); // see http://csharptest.net/?p=529

     using (Process process = Process.Start(psi))
     using (ManualResetEvent mreOut = new ManualResetEvent(false),
     mreErr = new ManualResetEvent(false))
     {
        process.OutputDataReceived += (o, e) => { if (e.Data == null) mreOut.Set(); else output(e.Data); };
        process.BeginOutputReadLine();
        process.ErrorDataReceived += (o, e) => { if (e.Data == null) mreErr.Set(); else output(e.Data); };
        process.BeginErrorReadLine();

        string line;
        while (input != null && null != (line = input.ReadLine()))
           process.StandardInput.WriteLine(line);

        process.StandardInput.Close();
        process.WaitForExit();

        mreOut.WaitOne();
        mreErr.WaitOne();
        return process.ExitCode;
     }
  }
```

... how can i call the function?

I modified the function with this:

```
public static int Run(Action<string> output, TextReader input, string exe, string args)
```

...because i already know the exe path and i wanto to directly pass args as direct string, but i don't know how to use the output and input variables.

By the way i understand the functionality but how to call it? 
To clarify please help me to fill ? here:

```
Run(???, ???, "console.exe", " -someargs");
```

A code example will be really appreciated... and again sorry for my stupid question and for my bad english language too.

Regards

Comment: Can we get indentation please?

Comment: I have no errors, i just not know how to call it, i just edited, please take a look, and obviusly thanks!

Comment: @GuybrushThreepwood the code is *still* missing indentations. :-(

Comment: Sorry alexander, i just approved and thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are not interested in the output the exe produces and you do not want to input any data into the process you can call the function like this:

```
Run((outMsg) => {}, null, "console.exe", " -someargs");
```

**Explanation**

The first parameter is a `Action<string>` which means it expects a function with one string argument. Every data that is received from the process on the standard output or standard error is passed to this function.
In my example above i just inserted a lambda expression which accepts one argument and does nothing.

The second parameter is a TextReader instance which seems to be optional and thus can be passed as null when not needed.
If set the content of the TextReader is written to the standard input of the process.

Comment: Dear Cargo thanks a lot, i read and read again your post and i think i understand now. Unfortunately i am not able to read the output variable (in your explanation is outMsg)

My goal is to get the output of the console.exe process then the output variable is imperative for me. You declared it as Lambda and it does nothing, how can i declare it to store the console output and get it back? Thanks a lot for you patience...

Answer (score 1):

Well from what I found out,

```
Action<String>
```

can be found - [What is Action<string>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2834094/what-is-actionstring)

```
Action<String> print = (x) => Console.WriteLine(x);

List<String> names = new List<String> { "pierre", "paul", "jacques" };
names.ForEach(print);
```

As for TextReader, it looks like you need to read a file, which you can find out how to do - http://www.dotnetperls.com/textreader

```
using (TextReader reader = File.OpenText(@"C:\perl.txt"))
{
    public static int Run(print, reader, "console.exe", " -someargs")
}
```

I can't tell you what to populate the properties of the obect with because I don't know what you're trying to achieve, but the missing parameters are basically two objects, you need to create these and pass them in. The links I provided should give you enough information on how to go about creating them.

Comment: Thanks this work and now the project compile and run, but i receive this error: System.IO.FileNotFoundException when it try to access the file you exampled "perl.txt" i think for admin rights...
There is a way to point it to a text variable and not file?

Comment: That's probably because you don't have a file called perl.txt, I just took it from the example given, the method is trying to read a file, so you either need to give it a file to read or as Gargo stated, pass in null

Answer (score 0):

Well, i found the solution than i post it here for other people (hope i can else please delete it..)

The way to get the output is so simple:

based on this code:

```js
        public static int Run(Action<string> output, string exe, string args)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(exe))
                throw new FileNotFoundException();
            if (output == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("output");

            ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
            psi.UseShellExecute = false;
            psi.RedirectStandardError = true;
            psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            psi.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
            psi.ErrorDialog = false;
            psi.WorkingDirectory = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
            psi.FileName = FindExePath("cdrecord.exe"); //see http://csharptest.net/?p=526
            psi.Arguments = " -scanbus -v"; // see http://csharptest.net/?p=529

            using (Process process = Process.Start(psi))
            using (ManualResetEvent mreOut = new ManualResetEvent(false),
            mreErr = new ManualResetEvent(false))
            {
                process.OutputDataReceived += (o, e) => { if (e.Data == null) mreOut.Set(); else output(e.Data); };
                process.BeginOutputReadLine();
                
                process.ErrorDataReceived += (o, e) => { if (e.Data == null) mreErr.Set(); else output(e.Data); };
                process.BeginErrorReadLine();

                output = s => ShowWindowsMessage(s);

                process.StandardInput.Close();
                process.WaitForExit();

                mreOut.WaitOne();
                mreErr.WaitOne();

                
                return process.ExitCode;
            }
        }

        public static string FindExePath(string exe)
        {
            exe = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(exe);
            if (!File.Exists(exe))
            {
                if (Path.GetDirectoryName(exe) == String.Empty)
                {
                    foreach (string test in (Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH") ?? "").Split(';'))
                    {
                        string path = test.Trim();
                        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(path) && File.Exists(path = Path.Combine(path, exe)))
                            return Path.GetFullPath(path);
                    }
                }
                throw new FileNotFoundException(new FileNotFoundException().Message, exe);
            }
            return Path.GetFullPath(exe);
        }
    private static void ShowWindowsMessage(string message)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(message);
    }
```

Which is able to start a process and read its otput, it is possible to call it with:

```js
        private void lbl_devices_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           int h;
           h = Run((output) => { }, "cdrecord.exe", "-scanbus -v");

        }
```

The code i added to use the Action is:

```
output = s => ShowWindowsMessage(s);
```

Hope this should help other people like Sythnet P and Gargo helped me, thanks a lot guys!!!! smack smack